# Combining two reclassified rasters using matrix of values with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

My purpose is to generate an accessibility raster for hiking trails using two reclassified rasters based on slope and land cover data. Both slope and land cover reclassified rasters have values from 1 to 5, so there will be 25 combinations in the matrix.

I need to assign an accessibility code for each combination of values (**eg: value 1 for slopes + value 5 for land cover = 2 accessibility code, so that ArcGIS will generate pixel values of 2 everywhere the combination 1 for slopes and 5 for land cover is present**).

In other words, I need a tool to automatically generate a code everywhere a condition is met (value X+value Y=Z value in the outcome).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension? You can definitely do this. The way that I know to do it requires the extension.